# Using GData and the Google Analytics on Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, gdata-api

I am wondering what my options are for using GData and specifically the analytics api on android to build a small widget. After searching around for a while I couldnt come up with any libraries with decent examples.

Are there any dedicated libraries with some decent examples / doco to do this sort of thing? I would like to target 1.5 but if the are 2.0 only I guess that is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) is a Google API library that supports Android.  It supports all Google API's (including gdata).  I don't think it has GData abstractions specifically for Analytics yet, so you might have to familiarize yourself with how the data feed looks, which you can do [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please try [**google-spreadsheet-lib-android**](http://code.google.com/p/google-spreadsheet-lib-android/)

Though its written for SpreadSheet, but you can follow this approach to access Google's other service API. At present it support SpreadSheet and Document List API and based on need I am planning to add more API support.

GData API doesn't work on Android, so no straight forward solution.

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
Prasanta